# Adding icon to app in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I know what I should do: add an "Icon files" key to the plist for the app, then click to the left on the disclosure triangle and enter some names on pngs. The problem is, I don't get a disclosure triangle to click. I'm using XCode 3.2.6 on a MacBook running 10.6.8. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should seriously consider updating your software. Current stable XCode version is 4.5 if I'm not mistaken, and it's terribly easy to change the icon there

Answer (score 0):

If Xcode 3.x is giving you trouble, you should seriously consider upgrading to 4.5.

That aside, you can close Xcode and then open your Info.plist in a text editor. Put the following in it:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>Icon-72@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-72.png</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon-72@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-72.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Now, you should have your icon information in your plist. Open Xcode and see if you can now edit your plist as you were trying to before.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have no doubt that what you say is correct, but the Apple Developer site is driving me nuts rejecting the password I just set this morning. Also, it looks like I'd have to upgrade to 10.7.4.  I'm a little leary of this, since I want my apps to run on 10.6.  In any event, I did another bit of Googling, and discovered a year-old solution using icns files. And that worked!

Comment: You can indeed target your apps for 10.6 if you develop in Xcode 4 on 10.7.4. Also, you didn't make it clear that you're developing for OS X. In any case, glad you solved your problem. If you want to select your own answer, you should post it to keep your accept ratio up so people won't avoid your questions in the future. Again, good luck and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks, Moshe. I did find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for Xcode 3.2.1 until I did convert the png icon file to an icns extension.
This site is useful : http://iconverticons.com/online/